# how can i find out which modules are loaded in apache?

Tags: apache-2.2

Is there a command in Linux to find out which modules are loaded and running in Apache?

Answer (score 6):

```
httpd -M
```

or if you're using Ubuntu try

```
apache2 -M or apache2ctl -M
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use apachectl (or apache2ctl)

```
apachectl  -D DUMP_MODULES
```

Answer (score 4):

```
httpd -l         # for static modules
httpd -M         # for shared modules
```

Or on Ubuntu:

```
apache2 -l         # for static modules
apache2 -M         # for shared modules
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use lsof.

```
lsof -p <apache pid> | grep mod_
```

This will give you a list of all loaded modules. This not only comes handy for apache, but all other processes to.